# Sufficient conditions for positive, symetric, bivariate function to be a covariance

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, covariance-function

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric function (i.e., $f(t_1, t_2) = f(t_2, t_1)$ for all $t_1, t_2 \in\mathbb{R}_+^2$). Are you aware of any extra condition that $f$ should satisfy for it to be a covariance function, that is, for the matrix $(f(t_i, t_j))_{i, j = 1}^N$ to be positive definite for all possible sets $\{t_1, \dots, t_N\}\subset \mathbb{R}_+$ or, equivalently, $\sum_{i, j = 1}^N c_if(t_i, t_j)c_j > 0$ for all $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks :)

Comment: maybe check out Sylvester's criterion ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion

Comment: One scarcely needs Sylvester: all possible $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ matrices formed from $f$ must have non-negative determinants.  That's a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Sure, Sylvester's criterion is a sufficient condition, but it seems that it's not easy to verify for an arbitrary function, is it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "verify."  In this case it's a simple algebraic requirement on the function.